# Swapping nodes in xmlNodeList C#

Tags: c#, xml

Assuming having the following xml

```
<test>
    <step>
        <var name="name1" />
        <var name="name2" />
    </step>

    <step>
        <var name="name3" />
        <var name="name4" />
    </step>

    <step>
        <var name="name5" />
        <var name="name6" />
    </step>

</test>
```

I m using XmlNodeList, seperated by "step". Is there a way to swap or replace a step directly in the xmlnodelist?

Need to make it like this:

```
<test>
    <step>
        <var name="name3" />
        <var name="name4" />
    </step>

    <step>
        <var name="name1" />
        <var name="name2" />
    </step>

    <step>
        <var name="name5" />
        <var name="name6" />
    </step>

</test>
```

Comment: Actually i cannot find a way to make it work, all I did loaded the xml file using

xml = new XmlDocument();

and then did 

xmlList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("step");

Comment: How do you distinguish the different `step`s?

Comment: xmlList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("step");

Comment: Do you just want to swap the `step` at position x with the one on position y or do you have any other criteria which `step` to swap with which?

Comment: I want to swap node 2 with node 1

Comment: Please note that the XML standard does not specify that an XML reader must read the nodes in the given order. The order of the nodes in an XML file does not have to be kept, as long as the hierarchy is kept. So swapping nodes seems like a bit of a strange request.

Comment: I edited the question to show you the result desired

Comment: Thorsten, in the xml file i m working on, the order is important, the one in he question is just for an example

Comment: If the order is important, I'd suggest (if there is any way to do this on your side) to add an attribute to `step`. Something like `<step position="1">...</step><step position="2">...</step>` and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use XDocument class instead of XMLDocument. This will swap the var nodes name3 with name6.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
class Test
{

    static void Main()
    {
        XDocument document = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        Swap("name3", "name6", document);
        document.Save("test.xml");
    }

    static void Swap(string nameOne, string nameTwo, XDocument document)
    {
        var nameOneNode = document.Descendants("var").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == nameOne);
        var nameTwoNode = document.Descendants("var").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == nameTwo);
        nameOneNode.Attribute("name").Value = nameTwo;
        nameTwoNode.Attribute("name").Value = nameOne;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but my guess is that this is too specific of a solution (?). Maybe because it would only handle the first layer of inner-nodes, and only their "name" attributes. But any good programmer should know that it needs to be modified to fit their needs.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the nodes in an XML file does not necessarily have to be kept when the XML file is read. For example, if your file looks like this:

```
<xmlcontent>
    <node value="Hello" />
    <node value="World" />
</xmlcontent>
```

The XML read may return the nodes like this:

```
<xmlcontent>
    <node value="World" />
    <node value="Hello" />
</xmlcontent>
```

To apply something like an "order" to XML nodes, you need to add an attribute you can sort by, like

```
<xmlcontent>
    <node index="1" value="Hello" />
    <node index="2" value="World" />
</xmlcontent>
```

In that case, "swapping" two elements would come down to swapping the index values.

Comment: The problem is that the nodes are in a xmlnodelist, which somehow is limited to any type of swapping. The order in which the c# load the nodes in the list is the same as in the xml file

Comment: Another way for my solution, how to replace a node in xml node list with another node. That would solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to do it, here is the code:

```
        XmlDocument xml;
        XmlNodeList xmlList;

        xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(path);

        xmlList = xml.GetElementsByTagName("step");

        XmlNode refNode = xmlList[1];

        XmlNode newNode = xmlList[0];

        xml.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(newNode, refNode);
```

Comment: Mark the appropriate Answer as answer if that helped you to solve your question.