# Swapping two elements and its sub-elements in a xml file using linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file whose few tags I need to swap.
Eg: In below sample, i want to swap elements (B and C along with its sub-elements) and update it back to the same xml.

```
<A>
   <B>
      <xxx>
      <zzz>
      .
   </B>
   <C>
      <nnn>
      <mmm>
      .
   </C>
</A>
```

so finally it should be something like below.

```
<A>
   <C>
      <nnn>
      <mmm>
      .
   </C>
   <B>
      <xxx>
      <zzz>
      .
   </B>
</A>
```

Any help in reading + parsing + saving-back  xml ?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Swapping nodes in xmlNodeList C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716799/swapping-nodes-in-xmlnodelist-c-sharp)

Comment: Dont think @FortyTwo - as here in my xml file , all tags are different and unrelated ( A - being root element , (B,C)- its child and B.C having their own sub-child. Also there are many more tags in my xml , so th code needs to find "A" first and work only on it.

Comment: The logic is the same. Find the *XmlNode* and insert it after the correct *XmlElement*

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about the VB.  The code to create the test XML will not be the same but the code to move A after C should be close.

```
        Dim xe As XElement
        ' to load from a file - similar to C#
        ' Dim yourpath As String = "your path here"
        'xe = XElement.Load(yourpath)

        ' for testing
        xe = <A>
                 <B>
                     <xxx></xxx>
                     <zzz></zzz>
      b stuff
   </B>
                 <C>
                     <nnn></nnn>
                     <mmm></mmm>
      c stuff
   </C>
             </A>


        'this should be close to what the C# will look like
        Dim holdB As XElement = New XElement(xe.<B>.FirstOrDefault) 'create copy of the B element
        xe.<B>.Remove() 'remove B

        xe.<C>.FirstOrDefault.AddAfterSelf(holdB) 'add after C

        ' to save file - similar to C#
        ' xe.Save(yourpath)
```

edit: Converted parts

```
XElement xe = default(XElement);
// to load from a file - similar to C#
string yourpath = "your path here";
xe = XElement.Load(yourpath);

XElement holdB = new XElement(xe.FirstOrDefault);
//create copy of the B element
xe.Remove();
//remove B

xe.FirstOrDefault.AddAfterSelf(holdB);
//add after C

// to save file - similar to C#
xe.Save(yourpath);

//=======================================================
//Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
//Conversion powered by NRefactory.
//Twitter: @telerik
//Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
//=======================================================
```

Comment: Thanks for ur code. Is there a way you could share a C# code ?

Comment: @ghatwala - ran the important parts through a converter and posted them.  I am not a C#'er so I have no idea if the code works or is proper.